# Compute Area of a circle

Tags: java

My program runs and after a few secs it just stops compiling. tried to assign input for the radius and it didn't worked. Would appreciate it if somebody can help me with explaining why my program fails to run.

```
package computearea;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class ComputeArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double radius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);


        double area;
        area = radius* radius * 3.14159;

        System.out.println("The area for the circle of radius " + radius + "is"
       + area);

    }

}
```

Comment: How can it *stop compiling after running for few seconds*?. Show us the stack trace..

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: _"My program runs and after a few secs it just stops compiling"_ It seems like you have more a _runtime error_ than a _compile time one_. My only guess is that you have an `InputMismatchException` because the decimal separator expected by your default Locale is not what you give to the Scanner.

Comment: @TheLostMind it says this...run:
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 44 seconds)

Comment: are you using any build tool or using simple javac command.

Comment: The code is just fine and it should work. How do you execute the code ? Oh and after reading the double from the Scanner you should close the Scanner via `close()`.

Comment: @ppuskar I use netbean

Comment: @dehlen just press run the program

Comment: Do you enter a double value after running the program ? If yes how do you enter the value (with a comma, or with a point . ?) Do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. It works as advertised.

Comment: 12
Radius: 12.0
The area for the circle of radius 12.0is452.38896

Comment: @dehlen i didnt have the chance to enter the input at all.it just keep running like that and then suddenly stopped.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right program?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik is it something wrong w my netbean? do i have to uninstall it?

Comment: Do you have another project, or another main class?

Comment: @Maurice Perry yes i checked it.

Comment: @Maurice Perry no, this programis the only one.

Comment: @user2971157 - Try running it on cmd line and check.

Comment: figured out what was wrong :) changed these:  System.out.println("Radius: ")                                double radius = input.nextDouble();  tq guys for helping me!